# JQuery multiple POSTs on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit my form to 2 different scripts on form submission. ScriptA that the form is submitted to redirects on submission. ScriptB doesnt give response of any kind, just writes the given info down.

I can't get the submission to work and I am not very experienced with JQuery and it is my first time so I was hoping someone could point out why my form isn't properly submitting with JQUERY.

Body of Html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
    //Send data to the email script
    $.post( 'authenticate.php', $('Auth').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {
        //data is the result from the script
        alert(data);
    });

    //Send data to the other script
    $.post( 'http://Service3.com/j_security_check', $('Auth').serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {
        //data is the result from the script
        alert(data);
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Body of html Form:

```
<form action=authenticate.php method=post name=Auth id="form" class="appnitro">
 <div class="form_description"><h2>Login</h2></div>
<ul>
    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Username </label>
        <div>
        <input id="element_1" name="j_username" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Password </label>
        <div>
        <input id="element_2" name="j_password" class="element text medium" type="password" maxlength="255" value=""/>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="buttons">
     <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" />
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

One off topic question I have is how do I fix the formatting of my code? whenever I post my code here I always get huge indentation.

Comment: RE formatting: Use spaces instead of tabs.  4 spaces = 4 spaces, but 1 tab = 8 spaces.  Also, use your editor to SHIFT+TAB the entire code until the left-most lines only have 1 tab before posting.  Once you copy it, you can tab it back into place.  Your editor should also have functionality to clean up the indentation across the entire document so you don't have extra tabs in indented lines.  Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  $('#form').submit(function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      url: "your_url_1",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data, status, xhr){
        alert('ok');
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        alert(status + ": " + err);
      }
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      url: "your_url_2",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data, status, xhr){
        alert('ok');
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        alert(status + ": " + err);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Those `$.ajax()` calls need to be encapsulated in an event handler of some kind. Also, why are you setting `async` to `false`? That will lockup the browser while the AJAX requests are sent.

Comment: I put it in my example to false because I need to. try with true, it should work too. test with firebug watching the network...you will see your requests if it work correctly!

Comment: it works now! the only thing is the first url is suppose to redirect on submission and at the time that isnt happening, any idea?

Comment: sure... $.ajax() make a request not a location. To redirect to an url after the two requests are done, put a window.location = ''; in the success function of the second $.ajax

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with your code. Instead of binding to the `click` event for the submit button, why not bind to the `submit` event for the form. Also when you serialize the form you want to target the form and you were selecting `$('Auth')` which will try to select any `Auth` tags (which don't exist).

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    //Send data to the email script
    $.post( 'authenticate.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data, textStatus) {
        //data is the result from the script
        alert(data);
    });
    return false;//this stops the form from submitting normally
});
```

Your second `$.post()` looks like it's sending the form submission to a different domain that the one the user is currently on. You can only do this with `JSONP`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax (do a search for `JSONP` and you will find excellent information on how to do this)

Comment: my form's name tag is Auth, name=Auth, so I thought it would take all the fields inside that form and POST them.

Comment: @Nadal To select an element by name uses this syntax: `$('[name="Auth"]')`. `name` is an attribute so we use the square brackets to search by attribute. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I have tried what you said but when I click submit page refreshes and nothing happens..

Comment: @Nadal If your getting any errors before the `return false` line then it won't execute and the form can submit. Did you change to a `submit` event?

Comment: what you and nicolas said I tried and it works, one thing though is I get "ok" because of the alert, but the script that the form is submitted to is suppose to say return a value, how do I get that returned value? for example, on submission it is suppose to redirect